# Uploading Plist to FTP

Tags: iphone, sdk, upload, ftp, plist

I've been googling a lot about this issue, and I just couldn't find the best answer for me.

My program creates plist file from user inputs such like "name", "phone" etc..

While I'm trying to save it to docs, all works fine.
 I'm using:

```
[thePlist writeToFile:thePath atomically:YES];
```

Now, I want to save it on my FTP server.
I tried this code and it doesn't work:

```
[plistData writeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://User:PassWord@DomainName"] atomically:YES];
```

(P.S. While typing the full address in safari, it is recognized and has no problem to access there, so the address is not the issue here.)

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`NSData` `writeToURL` only supports the "file://" scheme. So that will not work.

The best is probably to post the data with http to the server and have code on the server to accept the post.

From Apple's documentation:

The location to which to write the receiver's bytes. Only file:// URLs are supported.

Since at present only file:// URLs are supported, there is no difference between this method and writeToFile:atomically:, except for the type of the first argument.

Comment: i don't know how to write the code on the server to accept the post. do you have any idea how else can i do it?